# Page does not load until press DevTools (F12) in chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

My page does not load until I press F12 developer tool. I checked throttle which is  `No throttling`.
Not sure where is the problem and why the page does not load until F12.

Comment: does it exhibit this odd behaviour in other browsers? which ones work? which ones don't?

Comment: There's really no way to know for this one unfortunately. You should try more diagnostic steps and maybe update with that information. Does it happen in all browsers? Does the page stop working again when you close devtools? What kind of page is it? Is the browser still showing the page as loading? Or does it show as loaded but you just don't see anything?

Comment: @JaromandaX, The page is designed to work in Chrome and Edge but unfortunately it does not work in both.

Comment: `designed to work in Chrome and Edge` ... so, in the one browser ... my guess is that there's something wrong with "the code" or with "the browser" or with "the design"

Comment: @protango, this is asp.net application where I am trying to load the graph. But to do so, I have to press f12. Yes, it stops working when I close devtools. No, the browser does not show that the page is still loading.

Comment: @JaromandaX, if there is anything wrong with code then it should not work even I press F12.

Comment: I didn't say the code was syntactically wrong - that would be obvious, right. I meant to say either your code or your browser is causing the issue. It's a shame you've written code that is so browser specific that you can't test using a different browser to the only one you have tested with - to determine if it is a browser issue not a code issue

Comment: what extensions do you have loaded in your browser? perhaps your code and one of these extensions aren't playing well together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be due to the fact that the DevTools significantly shrinks your viewport. Try seeing if you can reproduce this effect by just shrinking your browser window without opening the devtools. If you can reproduce it that way, it means you have some JS/CSS which is hiding the content of your site on a normally sized window, but showing it on a smaller window.

If this is the case, you should check on your CSS styles first and remove any @media rules. if you're using some kind of library to render a graph (as you mentioned) then you should also check on the configuration of that.